# Convert ELMAH raw files to Fiddler SAZ traces

Tags: fiddler, elmah, elmah.mvc

Is there a way to convert Raw/Source data in XML or in JSON generated by ELMAH to a Fiddler SAZ trace file?

Comment: As far as I understand things, ELMAH has an option natively to collect a SAZ file. If there's a not such an option if you can share the XML or JSON I can look at writing an importer for you. `Help` > `Send Feedback` in Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mausch/ElmahFiddler adds a fiddle attachment when an error occurs ( when the errors are mailed). It extracts the *.saz file from the HttpRequest